# Android-Charts -- CandleStick Chart

Tags: android, android-studio, charts

Hi i am using https://github.com/limccn/Android-Charts  library for showing stock live data on chart in my android app. i am using CandleStick Chart of this library. everything is working fine except one thing is that i am not able to show tool tip when mouse over on any candle stick inside chart for display data. i am using below code for initializing chart. does any one know how to show tool tip or how we can attached any view when user mouse over on any stick of chart.

```
  private void initChart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < chartData.size(); i++) {
            //OHLCEntity(double open, double high, double low, double close, int date)
            ChartData chartdata = chartData.get(i);
            String dateString = chartdata.getT_Time().substring(0, chartdata.getT_Time().lastIndexOf("T"));
            String timeString = chartdata.getT_Time().substring(chartdata.getT_Time().lastIndexOf("T") + 1, chartdata.getT_Time().toString().length());
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":");
            String[] times = p.split(timeString);
            String dateValue = "";
            if (times.length >= 3) {
                dateValue = dateString.replaceAll("-", "").trim().toString() + times[0].trim().toString() + "" + times[1].toString().trim();
            } else {
                dateValue = dateString.replaceAll("-", "").trim().toString();
            }
            ohlc.add(new OHLCEntity(chartdata.getT_Open(), chartdata.getHigh(), chartdata.getLow(), chartdata.getT_Close(), Integer.valueOf(dateValue)));
        }
        ChartData maxds = Collections.max(chartData, new ChartComparator());
        candlestickchart.setAxisXColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        candlestickchart.setAxisYColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        candlestickchart.setLatitudeColor(Color.GRAY);
        candlestickchart.setLongitudeColor(Color.GRAY);
        candlestickchart.setBorderColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        candlestickchart.setLongitudeFontColor(Color.WHITE);
        candlestickchart.setLatitudeFontColor(Color.WHITE);
        // 最大显示足数
        candlestickchart.setMaxSticksNum(chartData.size());
        // 最大纬线数
//        candlestickchart.setLatitudeNum(5);
//        // 最大经线数
//        candlestickchart.setLongitudeNum(3);
        // 最大价格
        candlestickchart.setMaxValue(maxds.getVolume());
        // 最小价格
        int minIndex = chartData.indexOf(Collections.min(chartData, new ChartComparator()));
        candlestickchart.setMinValue(chartData.get(minIndex).getVolume());

        candlestickchart.setDisplayLongitudeTitle(true);
        candlestickchart.setDisplayLatitudeTitle(true);
        candlestickchart.setDisplayLatitude(true);
        candlestickchart.setDisplayLongitude(true);
        candlestickchart.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        candlestickchart.setDataQuadrantPaddingTop(5);
        candlestickchart.setDataQuadrantPaddingBottom(5);
        candlestickchart.setDataQuadrantPaddingLeft(5);
        candlestickchart.setDataQuadrantPaddingRight(5);
//      candlestickchart.setAxisYTitleQuadrantWidth(50);
//      candlestickchart.setAxisXTitleQuadrantHeight(20);
        candlestickchart.setAxisXPosition(Axis.AXIS_X_POSITION_BOTTOM);
        candlestickchart.setAxisYPosition(Axis.AXIS_Y_POSITION_RIGHT);
        // 为chart2增加均线
        candlestickchart.setStickData(new ListChartData<IStickEntity>(ohlc));
        candlestickchart.setOnDisplayCursorListener(new IDisplayCursorListener() {
            public void onCursorChanged(IDataCursor dataCursor, int displayFrom,
                                        int displayNumber) {
                candlestickchart.setDisplayFrom(displayFrom);
                candlestickchart.setDisplayNumber(displayNumber);
                candlestickchart.postInvalidate();
            }
        });

        candlestickchart.setOnTouchGestureListener(new OnTouchGestureListener() {

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             *
             * @param touchable
             * @param event
             * @see cn.limc.androidcharts.event.OnTouchGestureListener#onTouchDown(cn.limc.androidcharts.event.ITouchable, android.view.MotionEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void onTouchDown(ITouchable touchable, MotionEvent event) {
                super.onTouchDown(touchable, event);
                candlestickchart.touchDown(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             *
             * @param touchable
             * @param event
             * @see cn.limc.androidcharts.event.OnTouchGestureListener#onTouchMoved(cn.limc.androidcharts.event.ITouchable, android.view.MotionEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void onTouchMoved(ITouchable touchable, MotionEvent event) {
                super.onTouchMoved(touchable, event);
                candlestickchart.touchMoved(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             *
             * @param touchable
             * @param event
             * @see cn.limc.androidcharts.event.OnTouchGestureListener#onTouchUp(cn.limc.androidcharts.event.ITouchable, android.view.MotionEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void onTouchUp(ITouchable touchable, MotionEvent event) {
                super.onTouchUp(touchable, event);
                candlestickchart.touchUp(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            }
        });

        candlestickchart.setAutoCalcValueRange(true);
        candlestickchart.setDisplayCrossXOnTouch(true);
        candlestickchart.setDisplayCrossYOnTouch(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected stick data index, you can use:

```
public int getSelectedIndex()
```

If you want to get the touched Point, you can use:

1. Inside setOnTouchGestureListener:

   ```
   public void onTouchMoved(ITouchable touchable, MotionEvent event){
       new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY())
   }
   ```
2. Outside setOnTouchGestureListener (Activity, Fragment, ViewGroup):

   ```
   public PointF getTouchPoint()
   ```

For more features supports, choose SlipCandleStickChart.